# Using different panels for different sizes of items in WPF

Tags: wpf, panel, datatemplateselector

I want to use different panels for my container's item count. Is there a way that I can achieve this?

For example, I want to use `PanelA` for less than 5 items, `PanelB` for more.

I implemented the `DataTemplateSelector` class for this purpose and it seems to work. But when it comes to draw the UI element, I get no results but the blank white screen.

```
public class PanelDataTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{

    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        FrameworkElement element = container as FrameworkElement;

        MyViewModel VM = (VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(container) as ContentControl).DataContext as MyViewModel;

        DataTemplate template = null;

        if (VM.ItemsList.Count < 5)
            template = element.FindResource("PanelA") as DataTemplate;
        else
            template = element.FindResource("PanelB") as DataTemplate;

        return template;
    }    
}
```

Following is the one of the templates in my XAML code. Second one is just the same but `PanelB`.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="PanelA">
    <ListBox x:Name="ItemsListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ItemsList}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <Image Source="{Binding Path=Image}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Label}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <mynamespace:PanelA />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    </ListBox>
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate x:Key="PanelB">
...
</DataTemplate>
```

After resources, I have the following ContentControl section.

```
<Grid>
    <ContentControl>
        <ContentControl.ContentTemplateSelector>
            <local:PanelDataTemplateSelector />
        </ContentControl.ContentTemplateSelector>
    </ContentControl>
</Grid>
```

Thanks

Comment: There doesn't appear to be any error in the code that you have shown, so show your `Binding` code.

Comment: Please show *all relevant code*. That includes the collection control that you have applied the `DataTemplateSelector` on and the class properties of your *data object*.

Comment: No I would like to select the whole code in the ListBox. Other template is just the same but has PanelB instead of PanelA.
@Sheridan my class properties are not relevant. This binding is working without template selectors. But I am adding the ContentControl section to the post.

Comment: Instead of trying to change the ItemsPanelTemplate via a DataTemplateSelector, you should implement different behaviours in your Panel class, depending on the number of child elements.

Comment: If you can't even understand my simple request, then how can you possibly understand an answer?

Comment: @Clemens Thank you for the suggestion. But the Panel class is an outside resource. I cannot change the behavior unfortunately.